# WPF Class Events Not firing

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have created a Public Class called Transaction (see below) in my WPF App

```
Public Class Transaction

    Public Event Populate()

    Public Sub New(TransactionType As String)
        RaiseEvent Populate()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Then in my WPF Window I have instantiated an instance of this class (see below)

```
Public Class Window1
    Dim WithEvents lgTransaction As Transaction

    Private Sub buCreateTran_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles buCreateTran.Click
     lgTransaction = New Transaction("SALE")
    End Sub


    Private Sub lgTransaction_Populate() Handles lgTransaction.Populate
    MsgBox("Populate")
    End Sub
End Class
```

For some reason, the Populate Event does not fire in the WPF Form?? I am new to WPF so this is how I would do this in traditional vb.net. Does anyone have any ideas or pointers as to why it is not firing?

Answer (score 1):

You are raising the event in your Transaction class *before* the event handler has been wired up.

In other words, the delegate cannot be attached until *after* construction (either using AddHandler or the built-in "WithEvents" feature of VB).

You need to move this line of code so it happens after the constructor for class Transaction has completed:

```
RaiseEvent Populate()
```

Answer (score -1):

The `WithEvents` and `Handles` keywords in VB.NET are syntactical sugar for wiring up events statically at compile-time.

Here's the c# decompiled equivalent of the `Dim WithEvents lgTransaction As Transaction` declaration:

```
private virtual Transaction lgTransaction
{
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    get
    {
        return this._lgTransaction;
    }
    [DebuggerNonUserCode, MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    set
    {
        Transaction.PopulateEventHandler populateEventHandler =
            new Transaction.PopulateEventHandler(this.lgTransaction_Populate);

        if (this._lgTransaction != null)
        {
            this._lgTransaction.Populate -= populateEventHandler;
        }

        this._lgTransaction = value;

        if (this._lgTransaction == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        this._lgTransaction.Populate += populateEventHandler;
    }
}
```

You'll notice that the `set` wires up the handler properly, but because the line `lgTransaction = New Transaction("SALE")` must complete the `Transaction` constructor **before** it can be assigned thru the setter the event has been raised **before** the handler is wired up.

You need to make sure that the event is raised after the assignment, and not during construction for this to work.